# Sum all the elements java arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, sum

If I had: `ArrayList<Double> m = new ArrayList<Double>();`
with the double values ​​inside, how should I do to add up all the ArrayList elements?

```
public double incassoMargherita()
{
 double sum = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
 {          
 }
 return sum;
}
```

as?

Comment: How about `sum += m.get(i)`?

Comment: Hint: to get value from list at specified position you can use `m.get(indexOfPosition)`.

Comment: Alternatively, create a foreach loop and add sum to each element in the foreach.

Comment: or Use : JAVA 8 for int versions,
int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

Comment: This Question should be re-opened. It is valid, specific, and useful. Look at the up-votes on both Questions and Answers. Look at the newer information being added about using Java Streams for a *functional* solution.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Two ways:

Use indexes:

```
double sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
    sum += m.get(i);
return sum;
```

Use the "for each" style:

```
double sum = 0;
for(Double d : m)
    sum += d;
return sum;
```

Comment: or Use : JAVA 8 
int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

Comment: @AnandVarkeyPhilips that's like using a nuke to kill a fly :P

Comment: Why do you think it is?? Does it cause Performance Degradation?? Less and Clean Code, I was hoping for!

Comment: @AnandVarkeyPhilips The `:P` on the end of comment by Barranka means she/he was joking, or half-joking. See [Emoticons list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons): *Tongue sticking out, cheeky/playful, blowing a raspberry*.

Comment: @AnandVarkeyPhilips I didn't mean to offend you in any way, nor I think your solution is incorrect. Your answer *is* correct, and I was merely joking (thanks to BasilBourque for pointing it out)

Comment: lol... i was learning streams and thought it will be helpful for someone reading this here... then your comment made me think that it will create some performance degradation.. I did'nt know.. that's why I asked.. :)

Answer (score 37):

Using Java 8 [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
double sum = m.stream()
    .mapToDouble(a -> a)
    .sum();

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: what is a in that?

Comment: `a -> a` is a lambda function. Before the arrow is the parameter list (a) after the arrow is the body of the function (a). It's roughly equivalent to `double identity(double a) { return a }`

Answer (score 14):

Java 8+ version for `Integer`, `Long`, `Double` and `Float`

```
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    List<Long> longs = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L);
    List<Double> doubles = Arrays.asList(1.2d, 2.3d, 3.0d, 4.0d, 5.0d);
    List<Float> floats = Arrays.asList(1.3f, 2.2f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f);

    long intSum = ints.stream()
            .mapToLong(Integer::longValue)
            .sum();

    long longSum = longs.stream()
            .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
            .sum();

    double doublesSum = doubles.stream()
            .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
            .sum();

    double floatsSum = floats.stream()
            .mapToDouble(Float::doubleValue)
            .sum();

    System.out.println(String.format(
            "Integers: %s, Longs: %s, Doubles: %s, Floats: %s",
            intSum, longSum, doublesSum, floatsSum));
```

> 15, 15, 15.5, 15.5

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tested it but it should work.

```
public double incassoMargherita()
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + m.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I always say that to my project lead. :)

Answer (score 5):

Not very hard, just use `m.get(i)` to get the value from the list.

```
public double incassoMargherita()
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
    {
        sum += m.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even leverage the power of `reduce` of `stream`.
In Java 8, the `Stream.reduce()` combine elements of a stream and produces a single value.

```
public double incassoMargherita()
{
    // reduce takes 2 args => 
    // 1. initial value
    // 2. binary operator
    return m.stream().reduce(0, (a,b) -> a + b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
----
public double incassoMargherita()
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++)
    {
     sum = sum +(double) m.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that it is very old question but why did nobody offer easiest way without loop?

```
sum = m.sum()
```