# how to print an dynamic array with normal For loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having trouble printing the values of an array declared with ArrayList.
I am using the enchanced for to print its values but what if i want to sum them.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program
{

public static void main(String[] args){

    int sum = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = input.nextInt();

    while (x != -1){
        numbers.add(x);//xonoyme ta stoixeia ston numbers

        x = input.nextInt();
    }

    for (int y: numbers){
        sum = sum + numbers;
        System.out.print(y + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("to athroisma einai: " + sum);
}
```

}

the error is in the command
 sum = sum + numbers;

Comment: `sum = sum + y;`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242733/sum-all-the-elements-java-arraylist

Comment: I will try and stay with the rules next time i post. sorry for the question above which lucks of details.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thanks a lot for the advise.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
sum = sum + numbers;
```

*numbers* is the **list** of numbers you are iterating on.

You probably meant:

```
sum = sum + y;
```

*sum* is a primitive int variable. The `+` operator only allows you to add other primitive numerical values here. You can't add a `List<Integer>` to an int value.

Alternatively, you can use Java 8 streams here:

```
numbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

sums up all values in your list, too.

Comment: Without using streams ( i am at the beginning of learning java), how about summing my array like sum = sum + numbers[y] . Why it doesn't work?

Comment: sum = sum + y does the job. but what is y anyway. Isn't it like the index variable used in any array?