# How to find the sum of all the numbers entered before or after finding the Sorted array list?

Tags: java

I have written a program in ArrayList to find the sorted array. But I have to find the sum of the numbers entered as well.

I couldn't succeed in getting the results as it is in the array list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int add = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 5 numbers: ");
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) list.add(input.nextInt());

    System.out.println("add" +add);
    System.out.println("Sorting numbers...");
    sort(list);
    System.out.println("Displaying numbers...");
    System.out.println(list);

}

public static void sort(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        int currentMin = list.get(i);
        int currentIndex = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (currentMin > list.get(j)) {
                currentMin = list.get(j);
                currentIndex = j;
            }
        }

       if (currentIndex != i) {
            list.set(currentIndex, list.get(i));
            list.set(i, currentMin);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am looking to get the sum of the entered numbers along with sorting. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: while getting user inputs you can get sum of it. with help of empty variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum all the elements java arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242733/sum-all-the-elements-java-arraylist)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int sum = 0
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
int in = input.nextInt();
sum = sum + in;
list.add(in);
 }
```

Comment: @AbhishekDS Strange.  This doesn't do what you asked. *I am looking to get the sum of the entered numbers along with sorting.* I don't see a sort anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) list.add(input.nextInt());
```

to this

```
    int sum  = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      int num = input.nextInt();
      list.add(num);
      sum += num;
   }
```

the value of the sum is saved inside sum and you can do what ever you want with it.
I am using the For loop to add the values the user entered to a var name sum that is located out side of the for loop and when the for loop is done you have the sum

Answer (score 0):

You could just write `sum += currentMin` at the bottom of the `for (int i; ...` loop. This way you count every number exactly once, after it is put in its final place.